# bash script fails if `pwd -P` contains folder name with space in it

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

i have a bash script that sets up my work environment for me, sym linking files to the appropriate places in the home directory.

the following code works when its absolute path doesn't include any folders that have a space in their name:

```
    CURRENTDIR=`pwd -P`
    function make_sym_link { ln -s $CURRENTDIR/$1 $HOME/.$1; }
    for FILE in janus irbrc gvimrc vimrc.after vimrc.before
    do
      make_sym_link $FILE
    done
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with how the path isn't being escaped properly when there is a space.

An example working path is:
`User/stuartnelson3/Desktop/dotfiles`

While the path I have that isn't working:
`User/stuartnelson3/Google\ Drive/dotfiles`
(I added the `\`)

Is this the issue? What can I do to get around this?

Comment: `ln -s a b c` means `ln -s a b` and command `c`, not a file `a b`. So if you have spaces you have to escape it.  I think your assertion is correct. You can escape `<space>` with `\<space>` using `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes to include spaces and characters in filenames.

```
CURRENTDIR=`pwd -P`
function make_sym_link { ln -s "$CURRENTDIR/$1" "$HOME/.$1"; }
for FILE in janus irbrc gvimrc vimrc.after vimrc.before
do
  make_sym_link $FILE
done
```